# Why does slice(10, 50, 2).indices(10) return (10, 10, 2)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, indices

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# 1.11. Naming a Slice
# Problem: Your program has become an unreadable mess of 
# hardcoded slice indices and you want to clean it up.

###### 0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890'
record = '....................100          .......513.25   ..........'  
cost = int(record[20:32]) * float(record[40:48])

print (cost)

# name the slices
SHARES = slice(20,32)
PRICE = slice(40,48)

cost = int(record[SHARES]) * float(record[PRICE])
print (cost)


items = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
a = slice(2, 4)

print (items[2:4])
print (items[a])

items[a] = [10,11]
print (items)

del items[a]
print (items)


a = slice(10, 50, 2)
print (a.start, a.stop, a.step)


s = 'HelloWorld'
indice = a.indices(len(s))
print (indice)

for i in range(*a.indices(len(s))):
    print(s[i])
```

This is the example in Chapter 1.11 of the Python Cookbook.

```
print (indices)
```

This should give me `(5,10,2)` but it gives me `(10,10,2)`. Then the following for-loop did not print anything.

Why the results shown of my code is not like in the book?

Comment: What is `a` defined as?

Comment: @MattDMo What should a be defined as?    It is actually defined as a=slice(10,50,2) in my previous code -_-!

Comment: Please read about [MCVEs](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You need to post the **full code** necessary to reproduce your problem, including defining imports and all objects

Comment: @MattDMo [`slice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) is a python builtin

Comment: @mata derp. I'll edit...

Comment: Sorry.   I have edit it with complete code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually an error in the book. If you check the [errata](http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=0636920027072) and scroll down to page 19, there is this description:

> This example "a.indices(len(s))" leads to output that differs from the output as printed in the book, assuming the slice a is the slice a as shown in the example just above. It would work in the way shown, if a were slice(5, 50, 2) or so. Or am I wrong?
>
> Note from the Author or Editor:
> Change example mid-page to this:
>
> ```
> >>> a = slice(5, 50, 2)
> >>> a.start
> 5
> >>> a.stop
> 50
> >>> a.step
> 2
> >>>
> ```
>
> Problematic example at bottom should then work.

Comment: Thank you so much.  This link of errors is really helpful.

Comment: @fluency_03 no problem. All O'Reilly books have them, just search for the book on their website, go to its page, then in the "Essential Links" box on the right click on "View/Submit Errata" and you can check things out.